# How to build BlackBerry apps to .jad File with code signing key in phonegap?

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I build the project with BlackBerry Code signing key,then it can successfully build and i try download it.It give me a zip file name standardinstaller,inside got few file with .cod file.Because i got try build without signing key.It giv me a .jad file but now with a folder that cannot install to my bb smartphone. How come?

Any information provide me to build blackberry .jad file in phonegap build?

Answer (score 0):

For Signing your smartphone application -

[signing_your_smartphone_app](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/ww_publishing/signing_your_smartphone_app_1919664_11.html)

This link will Guide you.